# Set raster metadata (band names) in R on disk

Tags: r, raster, terra, rasterstats

I have a large raster on file. It can be read like so:

```
my_rast <- rast("my_large_file.tif")
names(my_rast)
[1] "value_a"
```

Using R or command-line GDAL I would like to change the name of the layer to something different, without totally re-writing the whole raster. How can I do this?

Note: I see there is a command in the [Python rasterio library](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.io.html#rasterio.io.BufferedDatasetWriter.set_band_description) to do this, but I don't see a similar one in R.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `names(my_rast) <- "new_name"`?

Comment: No, I want to change the name in the file on the disk without reading it in and then writing it out again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now use the `update(x, names=TRUE)` to write the changed layer names to disk (for file formats that support layer names, such as GTiff).

Example data

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.29
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
names(s)
#[1] "red"   "green" "blue" 
fname <- paste0(tempfile(), ".tif")
x <- writeRaster(s, fname)
```

Change the names, and write them to the file.

```
names(x) <- c("A", "B", "C")
update(x, names=TRUE)
```

Show that it worked

```
r <- rast(fname)
names(r)
#[1] "A" "B" "C"
```